# Component rendered before calling constructor or ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner with Angular 7.

When I start the application in debug with breakpoints in getKeys(), constructor and ngOnInit, I can see that getKeys() is called first. It seems to me that the component is rendered before calling constructor or ngOnInit.
Why is this and what can I do ?
It's a problem for me, because in ngOnInit I initialize a Map which I use in getKeys.

**Extract of my task-list.component.html**

```
<div class="task-group" *ngFor="let key of getKeys()">
  <h1><span class="key badge badge-secondary">{{ key.displayValue }}&nbsp;
      <span class="badge badge-light">{{ getTasksByKey(key).length }}</span></span></h1>


  <task *ngFor="let task of getTasksByKey(key)" [task]="task"></task>
</div>
```

**Extract of my task-list.component.ts**

```
...


@Component({
  selector: 'task-list',
  templateUrl: './task-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-list.component.scss']
})
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tasks: Task[];

  private mapExtractorByView: Map<TaskListViewEnum, KeyExtractor<Task>>;
  private _viewMode: TaskListViewEnum;


  constructor() {
    this.viewMode = TaskListViewEnum.byDate;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapExtractorByView = new Map<TaskListViewEnum, KeyExtractor<Task>>();
    this.mapExtractorByView.set(TaskListViewEnum.byDate, (t: Task) => new Key(t.date, formatDate(t.date, "fullDate", "fr")));
    this.mapExtractorByView.set(TaskListViewEnum.byTag, (t: Task) => new Key(t.tags, t.tags));
  }

  getKeys() {
    return CollectionUtils.extractKeys(this.tasks, this.mapExtractorByView.get(this._viewMode));
  }

  getTasksByKey(key: Key) {
    return CollectionUtils.getElementsByKey(this.tasks, this.mapExtractorByView.get(this._viewMode), key);
  }

  @Input()
  set viewMode(viewMode: TaskListViewEnum) {
    this._viewMode = viewMode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to console.log(this); in each method (getKeys, constructor and ngOnInit) and compare them do you see the same object every time? Also you can create a temp property and initalize it with a random number something like: dummy = Math.random();

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because rendering takes place before any Angular lifecycle hooks runs.  This happens in very short span of time (in milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe forgot to supply the tasks from the parent component?
if you initialize your tasks like `@Input() tasks: Task[] = [];`

the template should render and work succesfully, but the template will still be evaluated before `ngOnInit` as described in [Angular 2: A property set during OnInit is undefined on the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970470/angular-2-a-property-set-during-oninit-is-undefined-on-the-template)

Another option would be to use the `OnChanges` interface.
I created a stackblitz which shows how that would work -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoexkz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Note that I included two examples, the first loop uses `OnChanges`, the second just the method like you used.
You'll notice that the `OnChanges` example won't update if you push a task because `OnChanges` will only fire if the reference of `@Input tasks` changes (that's just how angular works).
This can be observed by clicking the `change Tasks` button.

Depending on your needs, `OnChanges` might suit you.